# "Trustworthiness rating" of chat flags in review bubble in form of prior flag acceptance stats

Tags: discussion, chat, moderator-tools, chat-flags

Disallowing users to flag chat messages might not be the best idea if someone is found frequently making bad flags. We usually give people second chances and hope they'll learn and improve. But to make it easier to figure out why a message has been flagged when it doesn't look inappropriate, we could show the users's recent flagging history rating as an extra piece of info in the flag review bubble.

Some examples of expected cases:

- (New flagger) 1/1 accepted flags raised in the past day. No prior flag history;
- (Bad flagger) 2/12 accepted flags raised in the past week. No prior flag history;
- (Good flagger) 4/4 accepted flags in the past week. 503/542 prior flags accepted;
- (Average flagger) no other recent flags in the past week. 11/23 prior flags accepted.

Usernames and more precise time frames are not visible to prevent abuse. Everybody and their moderators can see their own stats.

So if you see a flag with low stats, you know what to expect.

Answer (score 4):

A flag is literally a sign that someone needs to take a look at something.

Back when flagging was new on SE, they had something called flag weight - had no real value except for badges but.. people were afraid of bad flag weight.

An essential aspect of community moderation is for people to not be afraid to bring up potential problems.

And when someone takes a look hopefully they go look at the whole context of what was flagged, rather than who flagged it.

So, as someone who spends a lot of time around chat, I'm not convinced this would be particularly helpful in solving wider issues.

Comment: I thought maybe there is a problem with bad flaggers in highly populated chat rooms, but maybe I was wrong. Maybe there is no need for this system. I myself keep to a pretty low traffic room, so I don't know how it is in other places.

Comment: Bad flaggers are not a problem with appropriate responses.

Comment: I don't even look at those.